# Is this relation really transitive?

Tags: relations

$$A=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(0,2),(2,0),(2,2)\}$$

Hi guys can somebody tell me why this relation is not transitive? I know that is reflexive and symmetric and also thought that is transitive but my Math-Script say no!

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** $(1,0)$ and $(0,2)$ are in the relation.

Comment: So what does it mean ?

Comment: @Tiro: If $(1,0)$ and $(0,2)$ are in $A$, and $A$ is transitive, what ordered pair has to belong to $A$?

Comment: @amWhy: Neat! :-D

Comment: If this isn't a homework question, I think the full answer should be put up there?

Comment: @Joe: There is a pedagogical value for hints, even if the question is not a homework assignment.